# Google App Engine Deleting Version is not reducing Quota

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

I have a free App in Google App Engine.
I am nearing my quota limit for Code and Static File Storage. 
I deleted a couple version of the uploaded code 2 days ago. 
My Code and Static File Storage still reflects the same 0.85 G
How long does it take for the quota to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

From [How resources are replenished](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#How_Resources_are_Replenished):

> App Engine resets all resource measurements at the beginning of each
>   calendar day (except for Stored Data, which always represents the
>   amount of datastore storage in use).

and

> Daily quotas are replenished daily at midnight Pacific time.
>   Per-minute quotas are refreshed every 60 seconds.

So I'd re-check after midnight PST.